# What are some useful or interesting infinite generators?

Tags: language-agnostic, generator, infinite-sequence

What are some clever uses for infinite generators?  I've seen lots of seemingly trivial examples like *"list all even numbers"*, but I assume there must be others that have more applicability to real-world scenarios.  Concrete examples (in any language that support generators) appreciated!

I'll give a trivial sample as an answer.

Comment: The list of all off-topic questions for stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Haskell code on http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Haskell; that uses lazy lists (which are somewhat like generators) in a creative way to list all Hamming numbers.

Comment: Also has generator version in Python and C#.

Answer (score 1):

A **random generator** might be considered clever use.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial example: yield Fibonacci numbers one at a time (sans overflow checking, in C#):

```
public static IEnumerable<double> Fibonacci()
{
    double n_minus2 = 1;
    double n_minus1 = 1;
    yield return n_minus2;
    yield return n_minus1;

    while(true)
    {
        double n = n_minus2 + n_minus1;
        yield return n;
        n_minus2 = n_minus1;
        n_minus1 = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP asked for generators "that have more applicability to real-world scenarios".

Comment: @delnan - I am OP, and this is the example I said I'd post for illustrative purposes.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry. But is this kind of thing really what you're looking for? I'd consider this pretty much useless for real problems.

Comment: It is.  I am wondering if there were structurally similar mechanisms that are actually useful.

Comment: Why not post your trivial example as part of your original post?  0.o