# What does yield mean in PHP?

Tags: php, generator, php-5.5, yield-keyword

I've recently stumbled over this code:

```
function xrange($min, $max) 
{
    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
```

I've never seen this `yield` keyword before. Trying to run the code I get

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line x

So what is this `yield` keyword? Is it even valid PHP? And if it is, how do I use it?

Answer (score 497, accepted):

### What is `yield`?

The `yield` keyword [returns data from a generator function:](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php)

> The heart of a generator function is the yield keyword. In its simplest form, a yield statement looks much like a return statement, except that instead of stopping execution of the function and returning, yield instead provides a value to the code looping over the generator and pauses execution of the generator function.

### What is a generator function?

A generator function is effectively a more compact and efficient way to write an [Iterator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). It allows you to define a function (your `xrange`) that will *calculate and return* values *while* you are [looping over it](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```php
function xrange($min, $max) {
    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

[…]

foreach (xrange(1, 10) as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value", PHP_EOL;
}
```

This would create the following output:

```
0 => 1
1 => 2
…
9 => 10
```

You can also control the `$key` in the `foreach` by using

```
yield $someKey => $someValue;
```

In the generator function, `$someKey` is whatever you want appear for `$key` and `$someValue` being the value in `$val`. In the question's example that's `$i`.

Please note that, internally, sequential integer keys are paired with the yielded values, just as with a non-associative array. We can even set yield values with keys.

### What's the difference to normal functions?

Now you might wonder why we are not simply using PHP's native [`range` function](https://secure.php.net/range) to achieve that output. And right you are. The output would be the same. The difference is how we got there.

When we use `range` PHP, will execute it, create the entire array of numbers in memory and `return` that *entire array* to the `foreach` loop which will then go over it and output the values. In other words, the `foreach` will operate on the array itself. The `range` function and the `foreach` only "talk" once. Think of it like getting a package in the mail. The delivery guy will hand you the package and leave. And then you unwrap the entire package, taking out whatever is in there.

When we use the generator function, PHP will step into the function and execute it until it either meets the end or a `yield` keyword. When it meets a `yield`, it will then return whatever is the value at that time to the outer loop. Then it goes back into the generator function and continues from where it yielded. Since your `xrange` holds a `for` loop, it will execute and yield until `$max` was reached. Think of it like the `foreach` and the generator playing ping pong.

### Why do I need that?

Obviously, generators can be used to work around memory limits. Depending on your environment, doing a `range(1, 1000000)` will fatal your script whereas the same with a generator will just work fine. Or as Wikipedia puts it:

> Because generators compute their yielded values only on demand, they are useful for representing sequences that would be expensive or impossible to compute at once. These include e.g. infinite sequences and live data streams.

Generators are also supposed to be pretty fast. But keep in mind that when we are talking about fast, we are usually talking in very small numbers. So before you now run off and change all your code to use generators, do a benchmark to see where it makes sense.

Another Use Case for Generators is asynchronous coroutines. The `yield` keyword does not only return values but it also accepts them. For details on this, see the two excellent blog posts linked below.

### Since when can I use `yield`?

Generators have been introduced in **PHP 5.5**. Trying to use `yield` before that version will result in various parse errors, depending on the code that follows the keyword. So if you get a parse error from that code, update your PHP.

### Sources and further reading:

- [Official docs](https://secure.php.net/generators)
- [The original RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators)
- [kelunik's blog: An introduction to generators](http://blog.kelunik.com/2017/09/14/an-introduction-to-generators-in-php.html)
- [ircmaxell's blog: What generators can do for you](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/what-generators-can-do-for-you.html)
- [NikiC's blog: Cooperative multitasking using coroutines in PHP](http://nikic.github.io/2012/12/22/Cooperative-multitasking-using-coroutines-in-PHP.html)
- [Co-operative PHP Multitasking](https://medium.com/@assertchris/co-operative-php-multitasking-ce4ef52858a0)
- [What is the difference between a generator and an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223802/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generator-and-an-array)
- [Wikipedia on Generators in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: Please elaborate as to what the benefits of `yeild` are over, say, a solution like this one: http://ideone.com/xgqevM

Comment: Ah, well, and the notices I was generating.  Huh.  Well, I experimented in emulating Generators for PHP >= 5.0.0 with a helper-class, and yeah, slightly less readable, but I may use this in the future.  Interesting topic.  Thanks!

Comment: Not readability but memory usage! Compare used memory for iterating over `return range(1,100000000)` and  `for ($i=0; $i<100000000; $i++) yield $i`

Comment: @mike yes, that's already explained in my answer though. In the other Mike's example memory is hardly an issue because he's only iterating 10 values.

Comment: @Mike One problem with the xrange there is that its use of statics limits is usefulness for nesting for instance (For instance searching over an n dimensional manifold, or a recursive quicksort using generators, for instance). You can't nest xrange loops because theres only a single instance of its counter. The Yield version does not  suffer this problem.

Comment: Another interesting advantage of `yield` is that you can return more than one value to iterate, from a single cal to the generator function. This is because execution will eventually continue in the generator, after the yield (it's not a final `return`). See example here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#handler-subscriber-options

Answer (score 78):

This function is using yield:

```
function a($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        yield $item + 1;
    }
}
```

It is almost the same as this one without:

```
function b($items) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $result[] = $item + 1;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The only one difference is that `a()` returns a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) and `b()` just a simple array. You can iterate on both.

Also, the first one does not allocate a full array and is therefore less memory-demanding.

Comment: addt notes from the official docs:

In PHP 5, a generator could not return a value: doing so would result in a compile error. An empty return statement was valid syntax within a generator and it would terminate the generator. Since PHP 7.0, a generator can return values, which can be retrieved using Generator::getReturn().

http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Answer (score 30):

None of the answers show a concrete example using massive arrays populated by non-numeric members. Here is an example using an array generated by `explode()` on a large .txt file (262MB in my use case):

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');

echo "Starting memory usage: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br>";

$path = './file.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($path);

foreach(explode("\n", $content) as $ex) {
    $ex = trim($ex);
}

echo "Final memory usage: " . memory_get_usage();
```

The output was:

```
Starting memory usage: 415160
Final memory usage: 270948256
```

Now compare that to a similar script, using the `yield` keyword:

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');

echo "Starting memory usage: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br>";

function x() {
    $path = './file.txt';
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    foreach(explode("\n", $content) as $x) {
        yield $x;
    }
}

foreach(x() as $ex) {
    $ex = trim($ex);
}

echo "Final memory usage: " . memory_get_usage();
```

The output for this script was:

```
Starting memory usage: 415152
Final memory usage: 415616
```

Clearly memory usage savings were considerable (ΔMemoryUsage -----> **~270.5 MB** in first example, **~450B** in second example).

Comment: How much slower is it? I don't care about 270MB

Answer (score 27):

**simple example**

```
<?php
echo '#start main# ';
function a(){
    echo '{start[';
    for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++)
        yield $i;
    echo ']end} ';
}
foreach(a() as $v)
    echo $v.',';
echo '#end main#';
?>
```

**output**

```
#start main# {start[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,]end} #end main#
```

**advanced example**

```
<?php
echo '#start main# ';
function a(){
    echo '{start[';
    for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++)
        yield $i;
    echo ']end} ';
}
foreach(a() as $k => $v){
    if($k === 5)
        break;
    echo $k.'=>'.$v.',';
}
echo '#end main#';
?>
```

**output**

```
#start main# {start[0=>1,1=>2,2=>3,3=>4,4=>5,#end main#
```

Comment: So, it returns without interrupting the function?

Comment: so i should ask why ```echo join(',',iterator_to_array(a()));``` act differently for the first example ?

like: ```{start[]end} 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9```

Comment: ok nevermind i see now; `iterator_to_array` first collects all items then return as single array.

Answer (score 23):

`yield` keyword serves for definition of "generators" in PHP 5.5.
Ok, then what is a [generator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php)?

From php.net:

> Generators provide an easy way to implement simple iterators without the overhead or complexity of implementing a class that implements the Iterator interface.
>
> A generator allows you to write code that uses foreach to iterate over a set of data without needing to build an array in memory, which may cause you to exceed a memory limit, or require a considerable amount of processing time to generate. Instead, you can write a generator function, which is the same as a normal function, except that instead of returning once, a generator can yield as many times as it needs to in order to provide the values to be iterated over.

From this place: generators = generators, other functions (just a simple functions) = functions.

So, they are useful when:

- **you need to do things simple (or simple things);**

  generator is really much simplier then implementing the Iterator interface. other hand is, ofcource, that generators are less functional. [compare them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).
- **you need to generate BIG amounts of data - saving memory;**

  actually to save memory we can just generate needed data via functions for every loop iteration, and after iteration utilize garbage. so here main points is - clear code and probably performance. see what is better for your needs.
- **you need to generate sequence, which depends on intermediate values;**

  this is extending of the previous thought. generators can make things easier in comparison with functions. check [Fibonacci example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.comparison.php), and try to make sequence without generator. Also generators can work faster is this case, at least because of storing intermediate values in local variables;
- **you need to improve performance.**

  they can work faster then functions in some cases (see previous benefit);

Comment: I didn't understood how generators work. this class implements the iterator interface. from what I know the iterators classes allow me to configure how I want to iterate over an object. for example the ArrayIterator gets an array or object so I can modify values and keys while iterating it. so if iterators get the whole object/array then how does the generator doesn't have to build the whole array in the memory???

Answer (score 7):

With `yield` you can easily describe the breakpoints between multiple tasks in a single function. That's all, there is nothing special about it.

```
$closure = function ($injected1, $injected2, ...){
    $returned = array();
    //task1 on $injected1
    $returned[] = $returned1;
//I need a breakpoint here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //task2 on $injected2
    $returned[] = $returned2;
    //...
    return $returned;
};
$returned = $closure($injected1, $injected2, ...);
```

If task1 and task2 are highly related, but you need a breakpoint between them to do something else:

- free memory between processing database rows
- run other tasks which provide dependency to the next task, but which are unrelated by understanding the current code
- doing async calls and wait for the results
- and so on ...

then generators are the best solution, because you don't have to split up your code into many closures or mix it with other code, or use callbacks, etc... You just use `yield` to add a breakpoint, and you can continue from that breakpoint if you are ready.

Add breakpoint without generators:

```
$closure1 = function ($injected1){
    //task1 on $injected1
    return $returned1;
};
$closure2 = function ($injected2){
    //task2 on $injected2
    return $returned1;
};
//...
$returned1 = $closure1($injected1);
//breakpoint between task1 and task2
$returned2 = $closure2($injected2);
//...
```

Add breakpoint with generators

```
$closure = function (){
    $injected1 = yield;
    //task1 on $injected1
    $injected2 = (yield($returned1));
    //task2 on $injected2
    $injected3 = (yield($returned2));
    //...
    yield($returnedN);
};
$generator = $closure();
$returned1 = $generator->send($injected1);
//breakpoint between task1 and task2
$returned2 = $generator->send($injected2);
//...
$returnedN = $generator->send($injectedN);
```

*note: It is easy to make mistake with generators, so always write unit tests before you implement them!*
*note2: Using generators in an infinite loop is like writing a closure which has infinite length...*

Answer (score 4):

An interesting aspect, which worth to be discussed here, is **yielding by reference**. Every time we need to change a parameter such that it is reflected outside of the function, we have to pass this parameter by reference. To apply this to generators, we  simply prepend an ampersand `&` to the name of the generator and to the variable used in the iteration:

```
 <?php 
 /**
 * Yields by reference.
 * @param int $from
 */
function &counter($from) {
    while ($from > 0) {
        yield $from;
    }
}

foreach (counter(100) as &$value) {
    $value--;
    echo $value . '...';
}

// Output: 99...98...97...96...95...
```

The above example shows how changing the iterated values within the `foreach` loop changes the `$from` variable within the generator. This is because `$from` is **yielded by reference** due to the ampersand before the generator name. Because of that, the `$value` variable within the `foreach` loop is a reference to the `$from` variable within the generator function.

Comment: can you mention a benefit from this strategy?

Answer (score 1):

The below code illustrates how using a generator returns a result before completion, unlike the traditional non generator approach that returns a complete array after full iteration. With the generator below, the values are returned when ready, no need to wait for an array to be completely filled:

```
<?php 

function sleepiterate($length) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        sleep(2);
        yield $i;
    }
}

foreach (sleepiterate(5) as $i) {
    echo $i, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: So, it is not possible to use yield for generate html code in php? I don't know the benefits in a real environment

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini  what makes you think that?

Answer (score 0):

When implement PHP [IteratorAggregate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) interface, the `yield` keyword will be useful. Check out the documentation, there are couple examples either using `ArrayIterator` or `yield`.

Another example can be found is in the `php-ds/polyfill` repo: https://github.com/php-ds/polyfill/blob/e52796c50aac6e6cfa6a0e8182943027bacbe187/src/Traits/GenericSequence.php#L359

The idea is similar to the quick example below:

```
class Collection implements \IteratorAggregate
{
    private $array = [];

    public function push(...$values)
    {
        array_push($this->array, ...$values);
    }

    public function getIterator()
    {
        foreach ($this->array as $value) {
            yield $value;
        }
    }
}

$collection = new Collection();
$collection->push('apple', 'orange', 'banana');

foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    echo sprintf("[%s] => %s\n", $key, $value);
}
```

Output:

```
[0] => apple
[1] => orange
[2] => banana
```