# any way in PHP to access the KEY of YIELD outside FOREACH?

Tags: php, foreach, key, yield

Is there a way to access the KEY of the YIELD or it is acceptable only through foreach loop?

```
function foo()
{
    yield 'bar' => 'baz';
}

$foo = foo();
foreach ($foo as $key => $val)
    echo $key; // output: bar


$foo = foo();
echo key($foo->current()); //Warning:  key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does yield mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483806/what-does-yield-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Generators implement the Iterator interface, so `$foo->key()` what you are looking for.