# PHP 5.6 Generator Syntax: Can generators only be used in foreach loops?

Tags: php, generator

**I know that this can be super easily archieved without generators, however I want to understand generators better. Therefore please don't suggest using something else.**

---

I've got a class that generates filenames for screenshots (selenium):

```
class ScreenshotName
{

    private $counter = 0;

    public function screenshotNameIterator()
    {
         while(true) {
            yield sprintf("screenshot-%s-%s.png", date("Y-m-d\\TH:i:s"), ++$this->counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is: can I use such a generator in any other context than a foreach loop? e.g.

```
(new ScreenshotName())->screenshotNameIterator()->next()
```

for me this always returns null, and if I debug, it never enters the generator method. Also the PHP docs don't really mention this.

So my question is: *is* there a documented way to use a generator in a different context than a for-loop?

Comment: This post explains it in very good detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483806/what-does-yield-mean-in-php

Comment: you need to use `iterator()->current()` to get the value, and `iterator()->next()` to increment it. two step process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a documented way to do this. In fact Generator does implement the iterator interface as you can see it on this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php).

In fact the `foreach` keyword only work on iterators. So if you can use `foreach` on a generator you must be able to call `next`

Here is a sample code using `next` instead of `foreach` :

```
<?php

function evenNumbers() {
    for ($i = 0;; $i++) {
        yield 2*$i;
    }
}

$gen = evenNumbers();
$gen->next();
echo $gen->current();

?>
```

Comment: A code sample to illustrate would be really apropos here, instead of vague gesturing towards the documentation.

Comment: I added it as you suggested it

Comment: @DARK_DUCK: "In fact the foreach keyword only work on iterators". Being pedantic, I think it's incorrect. What about native arrays? I made some experiments and now I believe that even generators are handled inside `foreach` in some native way, not as iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code snippet to go with [Dark Duck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643707/199364). That is, it demonstrates how to use Iterator interface to iterate over all values. (Dark Duck's code is not complete.) Based on [a comment by robert_e_lee on Iterator doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#96691):

```
$gen = evenNumbers();
// If in a method that re-uses an iterator, may want the next line.
//OPTIONAL $gen->rewind();
while ($gen->valid()) {
    // This is the value:
    $value = $it->current();
    // You might or might not care about the key:
    //OPTIONAL $key = $it->key();

    // ... use $value and/or $key ...

    $it->next();
}
```

The above is roughly equivalent to:

```
foreach (evenNumbers() as $value) {
    // ... use $value ...
}
```

or

```
foreach (evenNumbers() as $key => $value) {
    // ... use $value and/or $key ...
}
```