# PHP memory exhaused while using array_combine in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach

I'm having a trouble when tried to use `array_combine` in a `foreach` loop. It will end up with an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes) in
```

Here is my code:

```
$data = array();
$csvData = $this->getData($file);
if ($columnNames) {
    $columns = array_shift($csvData);
    foreach ($csvData as $keyIndex => $rowData) {
        $data[$keyIndex] = array_combine($columns, array_values($rowData));
    }
}

return $data;
```

The source file CSV which I've used has approx ~1,000,000 rows. This row

```
$csvData = $this->getData($file)
```

I was using a while loop to read CSV and assign it into an array, it's working without any problem. The trouble come from `array_combine` and `foreach` loop.

Do you have any idea to resolve this or simply have a better solution?

## UPDATED

Here is the code to read the CSV file (using while loop)

```
$data = array();
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    throw new Exception('File "' . $file . '" do not exists');
}

$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
while ($rowData = fgetcsv($fh, $this->_lineLength, $this->_delimiter, $this->_enclosure)) {
    $data[] = $rowData;
}
fclose($fh);
return $data;
```

## UPDATED 2

The code above is working without any problem if you are playing around with a CSV file <=20,000~30,000 rows. From 50,000 rows and up, the memory will be exhausted.

Comment: Does `$this->getData($file)` only read the raw file?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Yes. I added that method into the question.

Comment: are you sure that the error occures within `foreach` loop but not on `$this->getData($file)` operation?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I am certain, because the error logged show me that it come from `array_combine` method in `foreach` loop. And `$csvData` is carrying the correct data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in fact keeping (or trying to keep) two distinct copies of the whole dataset in your memory. First you load the whole CSV date into memory using `getData()` and the you copy the data into the `$data` array by looping over the data in memory and creating a new array.

You should use stream based reading when loading the CSV data to keep just one data set in memory. If you're on PHP 5.5+ (which you definitely should by the way) this is a simple as changing your `getData` method to look like that:

```
protected function getData($file) {
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        throw new Exception('File "' . $file . '" do not exists');
    }

    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
    while ($rowData = fgetcsv($fh, $this->_lineLength, $this->_delimiter, $this->_enclosure)) {
        yield $rowData;
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

This makes use of a so-called [**generator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php) which is a PHP >= 5.5 feature. The rest of your code should continue to work as the inner workings of `getData` should be transparent to the calling code (only half of the truth).

**UPDATE** to explain how extracting the column headers will work now.

```
$data = array();
$csvData = $this->getData($file);
if ($columnNames) { // don't know what this one does exactly
    $columns = null;
    foreach ($csvData as $keyIndex => $rowData) {
        if ($keyIndex === 0) {
            $columns = $rowData;
        } else {
            $data[$keyIndex/* -1 if you need 0-index */] = array_combine(
                $columns, 
                array_values($rowData)
            );
        }
    }
}

return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what exactly `yield` doing in this game?

Comment: `yield` is a little bit more complicated than what can be described here in a comment. You should definitely read http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php, http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/what-generators-can-do-for-you.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483806/what-does-yield-mean-in-php

Comment: There is a small issue, I'm using this `$columns = array_shift($csvData);` to move CSV column names into an array, and array_combine will use that new array to the source array (from csv). How to force yield return an array instead of an object?

Comment: You need to do that a little bit different. `yield` will simply return row after row. If you need to handle row `0` (the first row containing the headers) differently, you need to check the `$keyIndex`. `if $keyIndex === 0` then you extract the columns, `if $keyIndex > 0` you continue your normal handling of data rows.

Comment: Could you update your answer with this, please? It still confusing me, first time I heard about `yield` and `Generators` :)

Comment: @ToanNguyen: Done.