# Multiple foreach loops exhausting memory for large data

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, foreach

We might consider `foreach` to be painful and a headache while using it to deal with thousands or millions of records. Even more so if we have a nested `foreach`.

For example,

```
foreach ($parent as $parentData) {
    // few conditional added here
    $parentObj = $this->extract();
    foreach ($chilren as $childrenData) {
        if ($childrenData['id'] === $parentData['id']) {
            $childrenObj = $this->extract();
            $parentObj->setData($childrenObj);
            // and even more evil things come here....
        }
    }
    $parentObj->save();
}
```

In my situation, I have two `foreach` loops. And each one contains approximate 50,000 ~ 70,000 records. `$parent` and `$children` are parameters passed to the method.

The raw data source both of `$parent` and `$children` are CSV files. And I'm using `yield` to transform them to be traversable with `foreach`.

There is no trouble with `yield`.

If you concern about the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37342184/2932590

I tried to `unset` both of `$parentObj` and `$childrenObj` at the end of first `foreach`, but unfortunately it's not working. I also tried to use the references `&$parentData`, but the result is same.

How could I make this work?

I was advised to use SPL Iterators in this case. Can anyone please explain me how it works?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @hkBst: Using multiple foreach and save objects inside foreach and PHP will throw error: Allowed memory exhausted....

Comment: So now that you are reading the data row by row, are you still trying to reconstruct the entire dataset in your $parentObj?

Comment: @hkBst: Yes. I updated my new code. Check the question updates.

Comment: what does/should `$this` refer to in each case and what does `save()` do?

Comment: @hkBst: I won't reveal the whole code. `$this` refer to current class as it always be. `save()` will save the data to the database.

Comment: Why people keep downvoting this?

Comment: Can't you use the database to define the parent-child relationship and query the related data you need?

Answer (score 0):

To use SPL iterator:

```php
// create a new ArrayIterator and pass in the array
$parentDataIter = new ArrayIterator($parentData);

// loop through the object one item at a time memory-wise
foreach ($parentDataIter as $key => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking for this. Btw, your code might not work without `IteratorIterator`

Answer (score 0):

SPL iterators are not a uniform thing but just the collective name for them (Standard PHP Library iterators). The ones available works quite differently but the following stack-overflow thread has already tried to explain their uses and pros/cons quite well.
[PHP - Reasons to use Iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247066/php-reasons-to-use-iterators).

Comment: I need to reduce my memory usage. That is why I choose Iterators, and yes I read that question before create this one.

Answer (score 0):

probably, `$parentObj = $this->extract();` doesn't use a reference and `$parentObj->setData($childrenObj);` makes PHP to create a copy from initial array for each element that is changed.

another approach is to move the pointer in a `while` loop:

```
reset($array);
while (list($key, $val) = each($array)) {
    $array[$key] = ++$val;
    echo "$array[$key]\n";
}
```

Comment: based on the information you provided it seems like there is a problem with the way you update an array - [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/1539119). for a better response, we need a more details about these methods $this->extract(), $parentObj->setData($childrenObj), `code`$parentObj->save()`code` at least in pseudocode