# rethinkdb changes() with yield doesn't return value

Tags: php, rethinkdb, yield

```
function fetchProduct()
{
   $cursor = r\table("tableOne")->changes()->run($conn);

    foreach ($cursor as $product) {
       yield $product;
    }
}


$product = fetchProduct();
var_dump($product);
echo "i"; //when the function use yield, this line executed. But when return used, it doesn't come to this line.
```

I understand rethinkdb's `changes()` will keep listening to the changes so i found that its better to use yield over the `$cursor`. But the `yield` doesn't return value to the calling party. But when return is used value returned.

How to make the yield to return any value when changes occur?

References:
https://rethinkdb.com/docs/async-connections/
[What does yield mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483806/what-does-yield-mean-in-php)

Comment: The async connections reference doesn't list PHP as implemented for async and as PHP is generally synchronous that would definitely require something like EventMachine or similar in PHP to work. I don't see it working like you tried.

Answer (score 0):

When using `yield()` this effectively makes the function 'return' an iterator.  So as per the example you linked 'What does yield mean in PHP?' you need to loop over the return value.

```
function fetchProduct()
{
    //$cursor = r\table("tableOne")->changes()->run($conn);
    $cursor = range(1,5);
    foreach ($cursor as $product) {
        yield $product;
    }
}


//$product = fetchProduct();
//var_dump($product);
foreach ( fetchProduct() as $product ){
    var_dump($product);
}
echo "i";
```

In the example above, I've changed it to use `range()` as the values, but this shows how you can process the return value and the difference between how you were trying to make it work and how it can work.

I would say that I don't know how this works with rethinkdb, but more about how `yield()` works in general.