# PHP yield without for?

Tags: php, generator

I've been looking at [some](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483806/what-does-yield-mean-in-php) of `yield` in PHP, trying to get a grasp of what situations one would use it in, and I began to notice that all of the examples I looked at had `yield` within a `for(...) {}` or `foreach(...) {}` statement.

Is there a way to use `yield` outside of a `for`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't require a loop. This works:

```
function foo() {
   yield 1;
   yield 2;
   yield 3;
}
```

One reason to use this is to use it as a similar feature as 'await' in Javascript.

It's possible for example to build an async framework that uses yield for this purpose:

```
function foo() {
   $response = yield asyncHttpRequest('GET', 'http://blabla');
}
```

This specific example is fictional, but it's possible (and has been done).

I made such an async library. Docs here: https://sabre.io/event/coroutines/

There's better maintained/more popular libraries out there though.

Comment: This is helpful, but I feel like I still don't understand all of what syntax exactly I can use to generate output with `yield`. Is it just sort of on a case-by-case bases? Like, you can use `for`, `foreach`, the imperative version you show, and the async style?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Are you looking for a reason to use yield? Or do you have a real use-case in mind and hoping that yield can help with that?

Comment: I don't have a real use case-- what I mean is that, I feel like I don't have an intuitive understanding of `yield`. As a comparison, I generally know what a variable is, and where it can go in PHP syntax. There are "places" where it can belong and work. What I am saying is that I don't understand the "places" where `yield` can go. I listed two in my question, you showed me two more, but I don't understand the underlying logic of why `yield` can go there... does that make sense? Maybe this question is too broad for SO

Comment: Probably too broad. `yield` is more generally a mechanism to pause functions and resume again later.

Comment: That's a very helpful insight. It seems to me now that it behaves like a `return` statement, which pauses execution within the scope where it's caled?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it =)